# Computing the inverse error function

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, error-function

I need a formula/series to compute the inverse error function, which is the inverse of
$$
\operatorname{erf}(x) = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{x} \mathrm{e}^{-t^2} \,\mathrm{d}t.
$$

Apparently the Maclaurin series for the inverse error function is
$$
\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{\pi} \left( \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{24}\pi x^3 + \frac{7}{960}\pi^2 x^5 + \frac{127}{80\,640}\pi^3 x^7 + \ldots \right),
$$
but I have no idea how many terms I need for it to converge (something like 4 decimal places would be fine for me, but I'd like to know the general answer). Alternatively, is there a better way of computing this function?

Comment: https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/files/gems_erfinv.pdf could be of interest for you.

Comment: [See This Referenece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Theorem_statement)

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.naic.edu/~jeffh/inverse_cerf.c

Comment: A Taylor series is probably not the best solution, as the function has vertical asymptotes at $\pm1$, which cannot be represented by a polynomial. The behavior close to $1$ is like $f(x)=\sqrt{-\ln(1-x))}$. It might be interesting to consider the function $\text{erf}^{-1}(f(x))$.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need a formula, rather than just using a standard routine like Matlab's norminv? In particular, note that erf(x)=2(F(x)-1/2) where F is the CDF of a normal random variable with variance $2$. So $\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(x)=F^{-1} \left ( \frac{x+1}{2} \right )$ which you can compute with norminv.

Comment: @Ian The reason is that I'd like a generic solution, i.e. something I can hypothetically implement in Brainf*ck, rather than relying on a specific language like Matlab.

Comment: @Bluefire But again, why? It's not really that language-dependent: Matlab has norminv, Excel has norminv, Python has scipy.stats.norm which has a function for it, etc. This is just one of those things that has been done. And the *way* that it has been done is not especially illuminating, when you open up the source code of these kinds of things it is filled with hardcoded constants.

Comment: @Ian That's not the point. Having a generic algorithm is always better than relying on your language having some feature. Do you know if Matlab's or Python's implementation have their source available? It doesn't matter if there are constants, just so long as I can translate it into pseudocode.

Comment: @Bluefire Matlab's is not. Python's is, but it is sufficiently integrated into scipy that it might be nontrivial to actually extract this particular algorithm. Looking at R's source might be a good way to go, though again you will find hardcoded constants that were originally computed using some other method (that maybe you do or don't care about).

Comment: In fact that is a good question: do you want to know how to compute the relevant constants, or would it be sufficient to just formulate the algorithm with constants included? In the latter case it would be pretty straightforward to convert an open source implementation into pseudocode for you.

Comment: @Ian I'm not really concerned with how a method is derived, just that it's a good approximation. I'll look at Python's and R's implementations, per your suggestion...

Comment: Another paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1974-28-126/S0025-5718-1974-0341812-5/S0025-5718-1974-0341812-5.pdf

Comment: @YuriyS Thank you, that's actually quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on the error function, but I can offer you this. To match the series you give, your $\mathrm{erf}(x)$ should be defined with $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ out front.

Also, the error in any series, will be on the order of $t^{n+1}$, where $n$ is the exponent of the last term you included in your series.  Since the even-powered terms in this series always have $0$ coefficient, you may as well assume that you included a final zero term, and so your convergence error will be on the order of $t$ to the next odd integer.  Since the inverse error function blows up to $\pm\infty$ at $\pm 1$, and you want $\lvert t \rvert^{n+2}<10^{-4}$, the series will converge accurately enough for you in the range: $\lvert t \rvert < 10^{-4/(n+2)}.$ Unfortunately, this doesn't converge very fast and you will need more and more terms the larger and larger $\lvert t \rvert$ gets.

Below, I've used Mathematica to show its built in functions are the ones you're referencing and to work out several more terms for you. From what I've seen of the error function (and reliance on built in functions in software), I don't believe there's a nice or simple general form. (Click the image to embiggen.)

[image: Mathematica code, verifying the series it gives is for the one desired.]